# Calendar table - Retrieve previous business dates

Tags: sql-server, date, calendar

I'm currently working on a project for which I need to prepare a calendar table a certain way.
Here is my referential calendar table:

```
+----------+----------+------+-------+-----+--------------+--+
| DATE_ID  | MONTH_ID | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | BUSINESS_DAY |  |
+----------+----------+------+-------+-----+--------------+--+
| 20160101 |   201601 | 2016 |     1 |   1 |            0 |  |
| 20160102 |   201601 | 2016 |     1 |   2 |            0 |  |
| 20160103 |   201601 | 2016 |     1 |   3 |            0 |  |
| 20160104 |   201601 | 2016 |     1 |   4 |            1 |  |
| 20160105 |   201601 | 2016 |     1 |   5 |            2 |  |
+----------+----------+------+-------+-----+--------------+--+
```

What I need to need is retrieve the DATE_ID field for the previous day, month and year, based on business day.
For instance, to retrieve previous day, I do my join on:

```
YEAR = YEAR
MONTH = MONTH
BUSINESS_DAY = BUSINESS_DAY - 1
And an extra condition if BUSINESS_DAY = 1, previous BUSINESS_DAY = 1
```

To retrieve previous month, I do something like:

```
YEAR = YEAR
MONTH = MONTH - 1
BUSINESS_DAY = BUSINESS_DAY
```

But I got a problem when there are more business day in the current month than in the previous month. In that case, I need to retrieve the max business day of previous month.
For instance, let's say March 31th is business day 22, and February has only 21 business day, the previous month date for both March 30th (business day 20) and March 31th (business day 21) wil be February 29th (business day 20, max business day of the month).

I've got a similar problem to retrieve previous year,as I'm doing:

```
YEAR = YEAR - 1
MONTH = MONTH 
BUSINESS_DAY = BUSINESS_DAY
```

If there are more business day in the current year current month than in the previous year current month, I need to retrieve the max business day of previous year current month.

How could I prepare my calendar table in such a way? I can't modify the structure of calendar table, I can only "prepare" my needed calendar table in a request.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was wondering how people create formatted table so easily :)

Comment: What do you mean with "prepare"? Do you need just to make a select statement with the dates? Can you just use a UDF that handles each day?

Comment: Yes I mean a select statement that will retrieve the calendar table as it is, with addition of DAY_MINUS1, MONTH_MINUS1 and YEAR_MINUS1 columns. It will be easier to not use UDF, but only a Select statement

Answer (score 0):

After thinking, here is the solution I come with:

```
Select RBC.*, RBC2.DATE_ID AS DATE_ID_DM1, RBC3.DATE_ID AS DATE_ID_MM1, RBC4.DATE_ID AS DATE_ID_YM1 FROM CALENDAR RBC
LEFT JOIN CALENDAR RBC2 ON RBC.BILL_YEAR = RBC2.BILL_YEAR AND RBC.BILL_MONTH = RBC2.BILL_MONTH AND ((RBC.BUS_DAY > 1 AND RBC.BUS_DAY - 1 = RBC2.BUS_DAY) OR (RBC.BUS_DAY = 1 AND RBC.BUS_DAY = RBC2.BUS_DAY))
LEFT JOIN (Select max(BUS_DAY) as MAX_BUS_DAY_M1, MONTH_ID FROM CALENDAR GROUP BY MONTH_ID) MAXRBC_M ON MAXRBC_M.MONTH_ID = RBC.MONTH_ID - 1 
LEFT JOIN (Select max(BUS_DAY) as MAX_BUS_DAY_Y1, MONTH_ID FROM CALENDAR GROUP BY MONTH_ID) MAXRBC_Y ON MAXRBC_Y.MONTH_ID = RBC.MONTH_ID - 100
LEFT JOIN CALENDAR RBC3 ON RBC.BILL_YEAR = RBC3.BILL_YEAR AND ((RBC.BILL_MONTH > 1 AND RBC.BILL_MONTH - 1 = RBC3.BILL_MONTH) OR (RBC.BILL_MONTH = 1 AND RBC.BILL_MONTH = RBC3.BILL_MONTH)) AND RBC.BUS_DAY != 0 AND ((RBC.BUS_DAY <= MAXRBC_M.MAX_BUS_DAY_M1 AND RBC.BUS_DAY = RBC3.BUS_DAY) OR (RBC.BUS_DAY > MAXRBC_M.MAX_BUS_DAY_M1 AND RBC3.BUS_DAY = MAXRBC_M.MAX_BUS_DAY_M1))
LEFT JOIN CALENDAR RBC4 ON RBC.BILL_YEAR - 1 = RBC4.BILL_YEAR AND RBC.BILL_MONTH = RBC4.BILL_MONTH AND RBC.BUS_DAY != 0 AND ((RBC.BUS_DAY <= MAXRBC_Y.MAX_BUS_DAY_Y1 AND RBC.BUS_DAY = RBC4.BUS_DAY) OR (RBC.BUS_DAY > MAXRBC_Y.MAX_BUS_DAY_Y1 AND RBC4.BUS_DAY = MAXRBC_Y.MAX_BUS_DAY_Y1))
```

I don't think it's optimal but it seems to work!